# How to test the value of a CSS selector using Capybara and RSpec? But the class is dynamic

Tags: rspec, capybara

The HTML page is supposed to have the following code:

```
<div class="UserSummaryPopup-avatar-77" style="background:= url(&quot;http://localhost:3000/images/medium/missing.jpg&quot;)</div>
```

How would you check for this using Capybara and RSpec?

Comment: Check for what exactly? that the element exists, that it has a specific style attribute?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CSS Selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

With this locator you select the class who start with "UserSummaryPopup-avatar"

> [class^="UserSummaryPopup-avatar"]